# Can I pause a AWS DMS replication instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-dms

I am using AWS DMS to move data around daily.

My replication instances are not used 24/24 hours.
Can I pause them in order to save on costs ?

If I cannot pause them, would it be bad to create and destroy them daily ?
Would it be too much work for too little savings ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DMS replication instances cannot be stopped. It is also not advisable to destroy and create it on daily basic. If you are not running a heavy migration you can take the benefit of free tier. AWS gives 750 Hours of Amazon DMS Single-AZ dms.t2.micro instance with 50 GB of included General Purpose (SSD) storage for free forever. You can check the free tier always free section.

Comment: "It is also not advisable to destroy and create it on daily basic." Why not?